# problem in where clause in linq

Tags: linq-to-sql

```
var src = (from s in Db.VCT_SITEs
                        join spl in Db.VCT_SPONSOR_SITE_PRO_LINKINGs on s.SITE_ID equals spl.SITE_ID
                        join l in Db.VCT_SITE_LOCATIONs on spl.LOCATION_ID equals l.LOCATION_ID
                       join spd in Db.VCT_SITE_PROTOCOL_DETAILs on spl.PR_SPONSOR_ID equals spd.PR_SPONSOR_ID
                       join c in Db.VCT_CONTACTs on spd.ADMINISTRATOR_ID equals c.CONTACT_ID 
                       where c.FIRST_NAME.StartsWith(txtFirstName.Text.Trim()) && 
                       c.LAST_NAME.StartsWith(txtLastName.Text.Trim()) && 
                       s.SITE_NAME.Contains(txtSiteName.Text.Trim()) && 
                       spl.PROTOCOL_ID==Convert.ToInt32(ddlProtocol.SelectedValue) && 
                       l.LOCATION_ID==Convert.ToInt32(ddlLocation.SelectedValue)
                       select new
                                  {
                                      NAME=c.FIRST_NAME + " " + c.MIDDLE_NAME + " " + c.LAST_NAME,
                                      s.SITE_ID,
                                      l.LOCATION_NAME,
                                      s.PHONE,
                                      s.FAX,
                                      s.SITE_NAME,
                                      s.EMAIL_ID,
                                      s.IS_ACTIVE
                            }).AsQueryable();
```

I have this linq query.Actually the problem is conditions in where clause r optional means these are search conditions.they may contain value or not. so i have to make a check on like if(ddlProtocol.selectedIndex!=0) then spl.PROTOCOL_ID==Convert.ToInt32(ddlProtocol.SelectedValue) condition work otherwise not. how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the programming language to construct the query.

```
IQueryable<VCT_Contact> cQuery = Db.VCT_CONTACTs;
string firstName = txtFirstName.Text.Trim();
if (firstName != string.Empty)
{
  cQuery = cQuery.Where(c => c.FIRST_NAME.StartsWith(firstName));
}
string lastName = txtLastName.Text.Trim();
if (lastName != string.Empty)
{
  cQuery = cQuery.Where(c => c.LAST_NAME.StartsWith(lastName));
}

IQueryable<VCT_SITE> sQuery = Db.VCT_SITEs;
string siteName = txtSiteName.Text.Trim();
if (siteName != string.Empty)
{
  sQuery = sQuery.Where(s => s.SITE_NAME.Contains(siteName));
}
IQueryable<VCT_SPONSOR_SITE_PRO_LINKING> splQuery = Db.VCT_SPONSOR_SITE_PRO_LINKINGs;
int protocol = Convert.ToInt32(ddlProtocol.SelectedValue);
if (protocol != 0)
{
  splQuery = splQuery.Where(spl => spl.PROTOCOL_ID == protocol);
}
IQueryable<VCT_SITE_LOCATION> lQuery = Db.VCT_SITE_LOCATIONs;
int location = Convert.ToInt32(ddlLocation.SelectedValue);
if (location != 0)
{
  lQuery = lQuery.Where(l => l.LOCATION_ID == location);
}

var src = (
  from s in sQuery
  join spl in splQuery on s.SITE_ID equals spl.SITE_ID
  join l in lQuery on spl.LOCATION_ID equals l.LOCATION_ID
  join spd in Db.VCT_SITE_PROTOCOL_DETAILs on spl.PR_SPONSOR_ID equals spd.PR_SPONSOR_ID
  join c in cQuery on spd.ADMINISTRATOR_ID equals c.CONTACT_ID
  select new {
    NAME=c.FIRST_NAME + " " + c.MIDDLE_NAME + " " + c.LAST_NAME,
    s.SITE_ID,
    l.LOCATION_NAME,
    s.PHONE,
    s.FAX,
    s.SITE_NAME,
    s.EMAIL_ID,
    s.IS_ACTIVE
  }).AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the conversion into a variable before the query:

```
int protocolId = int.Parse(ddlProtocol.SelectedValue);

var src = from ... 
where spl.PROTOCOL_ID==protocolID
   ...
select ...;
```

Comment: actually my problem is not this. Query is working fine if i put these conditions like if(ddlProtocol.selectedIndex!=0 && ddlProtocol.SelectedIndex!=0). My problem is if i didnt select anything from dropdown during search then the above query works without applying this if(ddlProtocol.selectedIndex!=0 && ddlProtocol.SelectedIndex!=0) if condition.

Comment: You can do that in the where clause. L2S will evaluate what can be evaluated locally and will generate a SQL query based on only what need to be evaluated by the db. E.g. _where (protocolID == 0 || spl.ProtocolId == protocolID) && (someOtherParam == 0 || spl.SomeOtherColumn == someOtherParam) ...etc..._